# IPv6 connection fails on Chrome, timeouts on Firefox

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, ipv6

I noticed there's a certain page taking a long time (5 to 10s) to load on Firefox. I traced the delay and it happens when trying to connect to a certain host, `bn.uol.com.br`.

Strangely, this delay only happens on Firefox, but not on Chrome / Chromium. It happens on Firefox 31.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, happens on Firefox 42.0 on Windows 10, and happens on Firefox 42.0.1 on Android 4.4.4; but it doesn't happen on Chromium 45.0.2454.101 for Ubuntu 14.04, or Chrome 46.0.2490.86m for Windows 10 or Chrome 34.0.1847.114 for Android 4.4.4.

**I want to end this delay on all OS'es and all devices, either by properly enabling IPv6, or by entirely disabling it.**

I had previously noticed intermittent `apt-get` stalling on random IPv6 addresses. I suspect (but I'm not certain) my ISP doesn't enable IPv6, and I also suspect (but also not sure) IPv6 is disabled on my wireless AP/router. I got suspicious and performed the http://test-ipv6.com/ test on both browsers on all OS's (same wireless network, same router / AP).

Here's the results:

### Firefox on Ubuntu

[image]

### Chromium on Ubuntu

[image]

### Firefox on Android

[image]

### Chrome on Android

[image]

### Firefox on Win10

[image]

### Chrome on Win10

[image]

## Additional tests

---

### wget (Win 10)

[image]

There's a long pause before the IPv6 timeout.

### More testes on a vanilla live USB Ubuntu

```
$ wget bn.uol.com.br
--2015-11-30 22:11:29--  http://bn.uol.com.br/
Resolving bn.uol.com.br (bn.uol.com.br)... 200.147.35.201, 2804:49c:319:430::126
Connecting to bn.uol.com.br (bn.uol.com.br)|200.147.35.201|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to bn.uol.com.br (bn.uol.com.br)|2804:49c:319:430::126|:80... [5s PAUSE HERE] failed: No route to host.
```

There's a long pause before the above IPv6 timeout.

```
$ ping6 bn.uol.com.br
PING bn.uol.com.br(2804:49c:319:430::126) 56 data bytes
From fe80::3e77:e6ff:XXXX:XXXX icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From fe80::3e77:e6ff:XXXX:XXXX icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From fe80::3e77:e6ff:XXXX:XXXX icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
^C
--- bn.uol.com.br ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5009ms

$ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::3e77:e6ff:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip -6 route
fe80::/64 dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 86397sec
default via fe80::9e97:26ff:XXXX:XXXX dev wlan0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 297sec
```

The third line seems to point to my wifi ap/router, although I'd suppose IPv6 is disabled on it (it's a Technicolor TD5130v2 and the user interface is quite confusing)

Comment: Could you post `ip -6 addr` and `ip -6 route` on Linux (preferably), or `netsh interface ipv6 show addr` & `netsh interface ipv6 show route` on Windows?

Comment: @grawity I added the response of those commands.

Comment: Hmm, so your router *still advertises* IPv6 accessibility via itself (the "default … proto ra" line), even though it doesn't have any addresses to offer. Is it a D-Link? Although I'm also kinda curious where the other "default … proto kernel" route comes from; it's a weird one.

Comment: It's a Technicolor TD5130v2. The control panel is a bit confusing and I know nothing about IPv6

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an IPv6 address, most likely because your ISP did not make the transition to IPv6 yet, like most ISPs in the world.

Your address `fe80::3e77:e6ff:feb4:41a1` is a link-local address,see [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6-ipv6/113328-ipv6-lla.html) for intance:

> A link-local address is an IPv6 unicast address that can be automatically configured on any interface using the link-local prefix FE80::/10 (1111 1110 10)

Besides, the reply from http://test-ipv6.com/ is identical to mine from home, where I **surely** do not have an IPv6 connection.

**Edit**

In reply to grawity's comment, I tried ping6-ing from one of my vps'es:

```
root@vps:~# ping6 -c3 bn.uol.com.br
PING bn.uol.com.br(2804:49c:319:FEED::FEEB) 56 data bytes

--- bn.uol.com.br ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2001ms
```

It tries to connect, it has an IPv6-capable DNS, no reply, because I do not have an IPv6 connection on this vps. Ubuntu, which is used in the OP, like surely all Debian's but at this point I suspect all Linuxes, is perfectly capable of self-configuring IPv6, if a non-link-local-address is found.

Comment: That's only part of the problem though. If the network really was without IPv6, then the connection wouldn't even be attempted at all due to no default ::/0 route. (I get an *instant* 0/10 after disabling IPv6.)

Comment: @grawity Wrote an Edit meant for you, could you tell me whether you agree?  Thanks.

Comment: That depends on what `ip -6 route` your VPS has.